# Update multiple records with one form in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update multiple records in a single form but am not sure how to proceed. The following is the code I am using to insert the fields into the database originally.

```
$case = date(ymdHis);

//register into database
if (!empty($p1_firstname)) mysql_query ("INSERT INTO cases VALUES ('$case','$date_booked','$p1_firstname','$p1_lastname ''$city’)");

if (!empty($p2_firstname)) $register_case = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO cases VALUES ('$case','$date_booked','$p2_firstname','$p2_lastname','$city’)");
```

I have an update form which displays data for however many records there are for each "case". How can I use UPDATE to edit information in different rows when each row has the same identifier ($case)?

Comment: Your rows don't have a unique identifier?

Comment: yes the do have an auto increment id, but when I select a specific record, I select by the case number in order to get several rows

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You reorganize your database to where it actually makes sense then proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

After normalizing your database then each of your records will have a unique identifier you can use for update queries.

Your current script is also prone to [sql injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). You should never trust a user's input.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE cases 
SET column1 = CASE column_id WHEN 0 then 'valueColumn1forRegisterId0' 
                             WHEN 1 then 'valueColumn1forRegisterId1'
                             WHEN 2 then 'valueColumn1forRegisterId2'
                             ELSE column1 END,
    column2 = CASE column_id WHEN 0 then 'valueColumn2forRegisterId0' 
                             WHEN 1 then 'valueColumn2forRegisterId1'
                             WHEN 2 then 'valueColumn2forRegisterId2'
                             ELSE column2 END;
```